# How to split a string using sybase query function

Tags: sql, function, split, sybase

String str = 'ce765e1bc7:abc879:53:7011:2'

How to split the string using sybase query function to value 7011

I have working stored proc for this. But wanted to know if sybase provides any inbuilt function to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position of the first character and length of the required pattern, you can use 'substring'

Syntax - substring(expression, start, length)

```
select substring('ce765e1bc7:abc879:53:7011:2',22,4)
```

If you only have string and the pattern to find but not sure about the length, you can additionally use 'charindex' and 'char_length' as shown in the example below:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @stpos INT, @stlen INT
SELECT @stpos = charindex('7011', 'ce765e1bc7:abc879:53:7011:2')
SELECT @stlen = char_length('7011')
SELECT substring('ce765e1bc7:abc879:53:7011:2',@stpos, @stlen)
END
```